How can I sync my overlay image with my main circle shape?
I'm trying to replicate the look of a solar eclipse. I have a startup screen that shows a <div> with a border-radius at 50% and a width/height of 20vw. This achieves the rounded look of course and with some box-shadow I pretty much accomplish a look.
But I'd like to enhance the aesthetic with an overlay with some kind of blend-mode (I've tinkered with color-dodge and hard-light so I'll do both somehow)
But I'm running into a wall right now because I cannot fit my eclipse overlay to be perfect around my circle. And I worry that specifically going down to decimal points will just have my design break later because of the units I'm using to make it responsive but I don't know how else I'd try to keep my current layout while syncing my overlay with my shape.
I feel like there must be a better way.
I'm new to stack overflow so I'm sorry if I formatted this poorly. I've attached the overlay image I'm using to this question as well as the image reference I'm trying to replicate
overlay image (incase earlier link doesn't work):
https://imgur.com/a/jYMDkaR


.startup-screen {
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 99;

    display: flex; 
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}


.startup-screen__eclipse {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 20%;
    height: 40%;
    padding: 5%;

    box-shadow: 17px 17px 18px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
                5px 5px 5px rgb(255, 213, 0),
                6px 6px 6px rgb(66, 230, 255),
                50px 50px 100px rgb(230, 207, 255);

    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
}


.startup-screen__eclipse__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    border: 2px solid red;
    top: 13%;
    left: 33%;
    /* mix-blend-mode: color-dodge; */
}

.startup-screen__eclipse__overlay img {
    width: 35vw;
    height: 35vw;
    mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}
<div class="startup-screen" id="startupScreen">
  <div class="startup-screen__eclipse">
      <div class="startup-screen__eclipse__overlay">
          <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/6OwwlZBM.png"> 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>




Are you trying to replicate the image with CSS only?

The image is not showing. To match the image with the background, we need to check what image it is. and the image has position: absolute; but the parent does not have position: relative

@NINE I added a backup in the post and also here: link

@prettyinpink trying definitely, i don't mind using javascript but this can be achieveable with only CSS I think... right?

@NINE sorry I just realized you meant the image is not showing in the code snippet, i fixed it. please let me know what I can do :(

HTML structure is very important, and the way you have it right now makes it a little bit complicated to do what you're wanting. I would structure my HTML more like in the following example.


html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.startup-screen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: black;
}

.startup-screen__eclipse-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 40%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.startup-screen__eclipse-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.startup-screen__eclipse-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  left: 47%;
  width: 52%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 17px 17px 18px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 5px 5px 5px rgb(255, 213, 0), 6px 6px 6px rgb(66, 230, 255), 50px 50px 100px rgb(230, 207, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
}
<div class="startup-screen" id="startupScreen">
  <div class="startup-screen__eclipse-wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/6OwwlZBM.png" class="startup-screen__eclipse-image">
    <div class="startup-screen__eclipse-overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>



I added a wrapper for both the image and the custom overlay, and then placed the image and overlay as sibling elements inside. That way I can size and position both precisely without worrying about it messing up child elements.

You are a godsend, thank you--is there a way to have the image (.startup-screen__eclipse-image) sit in the back with this current setup?

The image is currently rendered behind the overlay, but you can swap the order of the elements to change that.

You helped me so much, god bless
